# Expression.Convert within Expression.TryCatch

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to add some error-handling to a [block of code in the Effort library](http://effort.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39270a2f7cfc#Main/Source/Effort/Internal/DbManagement/Schema/DbTableInformation.cs) which generates an expression tree to perform a conversion and assign that result to a property.

The problem with the existing code is that a NullReferenceException is thrown when this expression is invoked at runtime when trying to assign null to a property with a value type. In this case I have no information about the property it was attempting to assign, so I want to throw a more specific exception.

Following is my first attempt to just encapsulate this logic in a try/catch block, and throw an exception if the conversion fails. Eventually I would add more information to the InvalidOperationException.

```
blockElements.Add(
    Expression.TryCatch(
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Property(result, this.Properties[i]),
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.ArrayIndex(parameter, Expression.Constant(i)),
                this.Properties[i].PropertyType)),
        Expression.Catch(typeof(NullReferenceException),
            Expression.Throw(Expression.Constant(
            new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled exception"))))));
```

In my mind this is what I'm trying to do:

```
try
{
    Property = (int)value;
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled exception");
}
```

However at runtime, that expression now throws an ArgumentException with the message "Body of catch must have the same type as body of try." What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to create a Block in the Catch expression to "return" some dummy value, even though it will never be hit due to the Throw?

Or am I approaching this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: I would certainly try wrapping both in an `Expression.Block` since that would more accurately reflect the code you are trying to recapitulate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In normal C# code, a method as a whole has to either return a value or throw an exception.

With `Expression`s, it works a bit different: each expression has a return type, and in the case of `TryCatch`, the return type of the `try` `Expression` has to be the same as the return type of any of the `catch` `Expression`s.

In your case, the type of the `try` is `int`, but the type of the `catch` is `void`, so they can't be used together. To fix this, you need to either change the type of the `try` to `void`, or change the type of the `catch` to `int`.

To change the type of the `try` to `void`, you can use [an overload of `Expression.Block()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630289.aspx) that lets you specify the type of the block (normally, it's the same as the type of the last expression in the block):

```
Expression.TryCatch(
    Expression.Block(
        typeof(void),
        Expression.Assign(…)),
    Expression.Catch(
        typeof(NullReferenceException),
        Expression.Throw(
            Expression.Constant(
                new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled exception")))))
```

To change the type of the `catch` to `int`, you would somehow need to change the type of the `Throw` expression. And since for a `Throw` expression, any return type can be valid (because it doesn't actually return), [there is an overload that lets you specify the return type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323901.aspx):

```
Expression.TryCatch(
    Expression.Assign(…),
    Expression.Catch(
        typeof(NullReferenceException),
        Expression.Throw(
            Expression.Constant(
                new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled exception")),
            typeof(int))))
```

I think changing the type of the `try` is conceptually clearer, because you don't actually want to return anything from the whole expression.

Comment: Ah, much nicer. Will delete my answer.

Comment: @jon-skeet and svick Many thanks to both of you; wrapping one's head around Expressions takes some getting used to! Accepting svick as answer due to the explanation of C# vs Expression return types which helps to clarify my confusion in "translating" conceptually from one to the other.